# HTML5 - is it possible to set one/same label for inputs in different forms?

Tags: html, forms, label

Recently I examined form attribute of label tag on W3C schools. [Link to the page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_form.asp), which states:

> The form attribute specifies one or more forms the  element belongs to.

My understanding is that I can set 1 label for radio buttons that are present in 2 forms.

I tried to implement this in the following way:

```html
<form id="form_1">
 <p><input type=radio id="test"> Testing case 1</p>
 <p><input type=radio> Testing case 2</p>
</form>
<form id="form_2">
 <p><input type=radio> Testing case 3</p>
 <p><input type=radio id="test"> Testing case 4</p>
</form>

<label for="test" form="form_1 form_2">Click to select testing case 1 and testing case 4</label>
```

As you can see, **only testing case 1 is being selected** when clicking on label, while testing case 4 radio-button no.

What do I misunderstand here?

Comment: That page kind-of contradicts itself in the section below. That statement is wrong. Use a more-reputable source for these thing [like MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Answer (score 1):

No.

A label can only label a single form control. An element's `id` must be unique within a document.

[The `form` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form) also only supports a single form id as its value.

The rules have not changed in the latest (as of the time of this answer) [nightly draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-fae-form).

> W3C schools

There's no such thing. You are looking at W3Schools. They are not affiliated with the W3C but get a lot of reflected glory from having a similar name.  This appears to be just another example of them being wrong.